# Start Server through email in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have requirement where authorized people will send an email and then an EC2 server should start.

We have decided to use SES and Lambda for this.

I have learned that we can set up rule in SES which then can trigger a Lambda function where we will have boto3 code to start the EC2 instance.

I was going through [Amazon SES Email-Receiving Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html) to do a Proof of Concept for this.

I have some questions:

1. To do POC in my AWS account do I need my own Domain name?
2. In real time when we set these rule where the authorized person will send email to which email-address address? And any particular format for it?

Comment: You might find this question useful as an alternate method: [How would I create a Minecraft EC2 server that automatically starts when someone tries to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60806487/174777)

Comment: @John Thanks.But we are looking for solution through SES.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a domain name (or sub-domain) with an MX record pointing to Amazon SES, or your existing email system could forward the email to the SES endpoint.

You could then configure SES to trigger a Lambda function for each incoming email. You could then code the Lambda function to turn on the EC2 instance. It could even look at who sent the email and make a decision about *which* EC2 instance to start. This would all be your own code, so the contents of the email is totally up to you!

For details, see: [New – Receive and Process Incoming Email with Amazon SES | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/)

Let us know how it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for this Info!! But my confusion here is where at which Email-Id i have to send email from my verified domain ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the "verified" stuff applies to _incoming_ emails on Amazon SES. Give it a try and see whether it works!